# Question on proof of completedness

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

$\textbf{Theorem}$: Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A \subseteq X$. Then $(1)$ $A$ is sequentially compact if and only if $(2)$ $A$ is complete and completely bounded.

I am given a proof on this but there is a step that I don't quite understand. It concerns the proof of $(2)$:

$\textbf{$(1) \rightarrow (2)$}$: Suppose that $A$ is sequentially compact. Then $A$ is completely bounded (this was already proven in a previous section). Now suppose that $(x_{n})_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$. Since $A$ is sequentially compact, there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_{k}})_{k}$ so that $x_{n_{k}} \rightarrow a$. Since $(x_{n})_{n}$ is a Cauchy sequence, then also $x_{n} \rightarrow a$. Thus $A$ is complete.

Now it is the last reasoning, namely that $x_{n} \rightarrow a$. Why will the Cauchy sequence converge to the same limit as its subsequence? I suppose it could be very obvious but alas I don't see it.

Comment: Try to prove it! Show us your thoughts. The idea is very simple

Comment: This is a general proporty of Cauchy sequences: if a subsequence converges, the the whole sequence converges (to the same limit).

Comment: Oh I see now that it is. :) For a random $\epsilon$ one has to let the difference of Cauchy terms be smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and idem for the terms of the subsequence and its limit and by then applying the triangle inequality it has been proven.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That only holds in complete spaces, which is precisely the property the poster is trying to prove.

Comment: @Demophilus You are completely wrong.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes you are right, sorry I was thinking of Cauchy nets and their subnets.

Comment: @bitsbit That will indeed to the trick.